Monitor MSHR / Fill register in Gem5 3 level cache system using Stat Package
I need some help with gem5 sample code to monitor MSHRs.

I designed a 3 level cache system in gem5. 

I want to monitor MSHR/Fill buffer and DRAM utilization. 
 

We can use gem5 stat package. [Gem5 stat package](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/statistics/#:~:text=It%E2%80%99s%20usage%20is%20straightforward%3A%20to%20assign%20a%20value,%2B%2B%20or%20%2B%3D%20like%20for%20any%20other%20type.)

However, I need some help with a sample code.

